# Project MESSAGE: You are running qmake on a generated .pro file. This may not work

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

When I'm loading a certain project using Qt Creator, I get this message repeated twice in the General Messages pane:

```
Project MESSAGE: You are running qmake on a generated .pro file. This may not work!
Project MESSAGE: You are running qmake on a generated .pro file. This may not work!
```

Screenshot:

[image]

This happens only on one of the projects (this project was created by a colleague, not me, so I don't know what's different about it).

What does this message mean? Is there something that should be fixed in the .pro file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Project Message:` usually indicates that the following text was printed in the qmake file using `message(text)`.

In that case, your best hope is to grep for the message in all `.pro` files, find out where it comes from and asking your colleague what that message is supposed to mean if you can't figure it out.

**Edit:** I just found out that the *Qt Visual Studio Integration* puts this message in autogenerated qmake files. If you or your colleague are using the VS integration, you could remove that message if you do not intend to re-generate the `.pro` file. The message is basically there to tell you that you might have to adjust some things to make the project build correctly (which it seems to do in your case).

In that case, the code generally looks like this:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Add-in.
# ------------------------------------------------------

# This is a reminder that you are using a generated .pro file.
# Remove it when you are finished editing this file.
message("You are running qmake on a generated .pro file. This may not work!")
```